# Is Windows Server 2016 part of Internet Explorer Removal on Feb 14 2023

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, windows-server-2016

I have a machine running Windows Server 2016 and uses Internet Explorer. On February 14, 2023, will Internet Explorer be disabled/removed from this machine? If so, which update is being used? Thank you

The closest applicable references that could be found are here:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/427965/is-windows-server-included-in-retiring-internet-ex

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft blog
[The future of Internet Explorer on Windows 10 is in Microsoft Edge](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/)
says this:

> the Internet Explorer 11 desktop application will be retired and go out of support on June 15, 2022, **for certain versions of Windows 10**.

Your Windows Server 2016 is therefore safe.
The Edge browser can be installed but is not a requirement.

See also
[Lifecycle FAQ - Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge).